# what does ? mean in python pyodbc module

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Testing_Param(Seed_Number,Cycle_Name) VALUES (?,?)",('0','CoupleIn'))
```

what does the "?" mean in the code?
When I try to replace the ? to %s for the "CoupleIn" which is the string and %d for the "0", why does it appear error message:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

I am new to the pyodbc module to do transfering data from Python into Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a place holder for parameter values, '0' and 'Couple'. cursor.execute will substitute the values in place of ?s.

Answer (score 6):

`?` is the placeholder for the substitution engine.  The `cursor.execute` function is responsible for properly escaping the values in the tuple and inserting them into the query where the respective question marks are to form a valid query.  This keeps you safe from [sql injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/) where normal string interpolation would leave your database vulnerable to attackers.

You can read more about the standard python database apis in [PEP-0249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) -- Specifically, your database wrapper is using `qmark` paramstyle.

Comment: Tq for your explaination

Answer (score 2):

The two question marks are placeholders for the parameters `0` and `CoupleIn`, respectively.
 This is similar for the text formatting in Python where the placeholder for a variable  is `%`.

See http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/ under the paragraph `Parameters`

Comment: yes I know about using the % but why do i encounter an error when i use %d for '0' and %s  for "CoupleIn' ?

Comment: I said it is similar just for illustration. In the above example you need to follow the syntax of `pyodbc` which just uses `?`.