# pyodbc execute SQL code

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to use pyodbc cursor execute the right way to prevent injection attacks, as suggested here:
[what does ? mean in python pyodbc module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885053/what-does-mean-in-python-pyodbc-module)

My code is as follows:

```
query = """\
SELECT 
    ?,count(*)
FROM 
    ?
WHERE 
    ?=?
""", ('date', 'myTable', 'date', '2017-05-08')
cursor.execute(query)
```

And I get an error:

```
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

For the right answer I'd want to:

1. Keep the question mark format to avoid SQL injection attacks
2. Keep the triple quotes format so I can write long SQL queries and not loose code readability.

Is there a way to achieve this?  I know I could use `""" %s """ %('table')` format type but that defeats the purpose of this question.

Comment: Ok, your edit came at the same time as my comment. Where are you getting `myTable` and `date` strings from? It's unlikely that these would be coming from freetext anywhere in your setup? A _value_ for the date might be entered by a user, but would they specify that it was going to be written into the `date` column of your table? In other words, could you be vulnerable to SQL injection from formatting the table name and the column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1. `query` is a tuple. The way to execute a parameterized query is as
   follows:

   ```
   query = """SELECT ?,count(*)
              FROM ?
              WHERE ?=? """
   args = ('date', 'myTable', 'date', '2017-05-08')
   cursor.execute(query, args)
   ```

   You could pass `query` with `*`. This would expand `query` to a string and a tuple which is what `execute` expects:

   ```
   cursor.execute(*query)  # 'query' here is defined as it is in your example
   ```
2. But, that won't work. You can not use parameterized query to use parameters in the select and from clauses. You can also not use parameters for the column name in the where clause.

You (usually) don't have to worry about SQL injection if the value isn't inputted  by the user (or if the user can't change it in anyway).