# How can I perform an UPDATE if EXISTS based on existing data in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am pulling data from an application (via Python) and writing that data into a SQL Server database. My initial data loads, however I will need to UPDATE that data based on subsequent API retrievals from my Python script.  While I am successfully able to update all existing rows in the my database I only want to update the values that are different. To visualize:

```
dev_name    userID
========    ======
abc          def
ghi          jkl
mno          NULL
```

When Python pulls new data and sees a different `uid` value for row 'mno' for example, the UPDATE statement should only update that row. Non NULL columns could be updated as well.  I thought the following should have worked, however it doesn't.

```
rslt = cursor.execute(IF EXISTS(SELECT device_name from Devices where device_name = ?) UPDATE Devices SET userID = (?) where device_name = ? and userID <> ?", dev, uid, dev, uid)
```

To clarify, the parameters of `dev` and `uid` refer to the Python variables that contain the data from the API call.

Any clarification or explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "IF EXISTS" is not valid SQL and it's pointless anyways.  UPDATE will only update rows that match the WHERE condition, if they exist.  if none exist then nothing gets updated

Comment: note in the case where userID is NULL, comparing it to a value will always be false, so you should use `and (userID <> ? or userID is null)`

Comment: The only exception would be a LEFT JOIN, along with an "is null" operator to validate if the value exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, the WHERE predicate is how you determine existence of a record.

Presumably you want to set the userID to the current owner of the device. Supposing the new userID is 'pqr', then:

```
UPDATE Devices 
SET userID = 'pqr'
where device_name = 'mno'
and userID <> 'pqr';
```

So for this specific example:

```
query = """UPDATE Devices 
           SET userID = ?
           where device_name = ?
           and userID <> ? """
args = ('pqr', 'mno', 'pqr')
cursor.execute(query, args)
```

Or in your case:

```
query = """UPDATE Devices 
           SET userID = ?
           where device_name = ?
           and userID <> ? """
args = (uid, dev, uid)
cursor.execute(query, args)
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855514/pyodbc-execute-sql-code)

EDIT to handle NULL values:

```
query = """UPDATE Devices 
           SET userID = ? 
           WHERE device_name = ? 
           AND COALESCE(userID,'NULL') <> COALESCE(?,'NULL'))) """ 
args = (uid,dev,uid)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works great.  To echo @Kurt I had to add the 'userID <> ? or userID is null' as that column allows for NULL.

Comment: You can also use `and coalesce(userID,'') <> ?`. If UserID is null, COALESCE to empty string will put an empty string in the comparison, which doesn't have the same problem as NULL.

Comment: Can someone also explain why the query won't update to be NULL?  Using the above query, if there is currently data in a row and needs to be updated to either a 0 or NULL, that row is bypassed.  I would think the <> should have accounted for that?

Comment: You can't compare with NULL using the not equals operator (or the equals operator). You need to COALESCE both sides of the (in)equality to an empty string in order to draw a valid comparison. Like this:
`WHERE COALESCE(userID,'') <> COALESCE( ?, '')`
Alternatively, you can handle nulls in this way:
`WHERE COALESCE(userID,'') <> ? OR (? IS NULL AND userID IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: I have been trying iterations of this all day and cannot seem to get it correct.  I get the basic concept of 'coalesce', however my syntax is off and not updating both populated and NULL values. I have the following;

'''query = UPDATE Devices SET userID = ? where device_name = ? and userID <> ?
                or device_name = ? and COALESCE(userID,'NULL') <> ?"""

                args = (uid,dev,uid,dev,uid)'''

Can you advise where things are falling apart?  I am struggling to understand the full logic.  Thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer. If you still get problems, test if the uid param is null in the code and execute one statement for uid is not null and another fors uid is null

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I am still learning SQL syntax and visualizing it helps me to better understand it.